# Normalizing value using 3 points / levels

Tags: time-series, python, normalization

I am using following formula to normalize number:

```
new = ((current - low) / (high - low)) * 100
```

But i need middle number to be the mode of the data. So in this case i will give you real example:

```
ETHEREUM PRICE: 121.18
low range: 119.09
high range: 121.56
middle: 120.95

high-middle = 0.61
low-middle = 1.86
```

If I go with my initial formula, 50 is not equal to my middle range. There are two parts here. Values greater than 50 and lower than 50. Is there a way to make this work? I know it's a bit complicated but this is what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this (in pseudocode)

```
if (current <= middle) 
    if (middle == low) 
        new == 50
    else
        new = ((current - low) / (middle - low)) * 50 
else 
    if (middle == high)
        new == 50
    else
        new = 50  + ((current - middle) / (high - middle)) * 50
```

which avoids division by zero when `middle` could be equal to `low` or `high`.  If that cannot happen then you only really need the two long lines